# Multiple parameters in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to set up a browser to browse through a tree. 
Every time a leave is selected, its children can be selected.

Since I want to make generic, I only want to specify one route.

Unfortunatly, that does not really work...
This works

```
RouterModule.forRoot( [
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/browser', pathMatch: 'full' },
{
    path: 'browser', children: [
    {
        path: '',
        component: BrowserComponent
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        component: BrowserComponent
    }
]
},
```

] )

But then I am not able to read the params. This prints an emtpy object

```
this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
   console.log(params);
});
```

I think it should be something like this:

```
{ path: '**/:id', component: BrowserComponent }
```

But that does also not work..:/
Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

PS: In rails I would do it like this:

```
get 'browser/*id',
```

Comment: What is `this.route`'s type? `ActivatedRoute`?

Comment: Yes. `this.route` is declared in the costructor `private route: ActivatedRoute`

Comment: Can you expand your route config a bit please?

Comment: I have add the complete route config. Its still very small...

Comment: The ** path is the wildcard path as you know. Are you trying to pass a parameter to the wildcard route?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correct. If I make a request to localhost/browse/1, 1 you should be the parameter

Comment: Check the plunker

Answer (score 1):

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kWSOa8i6095e0a5pBlgq?p=preview

In order to get the params change the routeconfig like this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot( [
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/browser', pathMatch: 'full' },
{
    path: 'browser', children: [
    {
        path: ':id',
        component: BrowserComponent
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        component: AnotherComponent
    }
]
},
```

This way, when the user goes to the url browser/1, you can see 1 in the params. I also suggest you to change the component of the wildcard route (**) because I assume you are going to use a parameter inside your BrowserComponent and if your user doesn't provide a parameter it should go to an error page.

Comment: This does only work with one parameter. browser/1/2 does not work.

Comment: @Moritz of course. You need a deeper route config for that. Not `forRoot` but `forChildren`

Comment: obviously I could add another static route. However, it should be generic since I do not know how many IDs it will be. It can be /browser, /browser/1, /browser/1/2, /browser/1/2/3... Finally, I only care about the last id. The other IDs will be used for history, e.g. breadcrumb.

Comment: @m13r like this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40669434/angular-2-routing-and-component-childrens

Comment: Exactly, where N >= 0.

Comment: @m13r I don't know whether you can do that or not. Let's wait for an answer on the other question.

Comment: I am sure there as to be a way to accomplish this.