# Angular 2 routing and component childrens

Tags: angular, typescript

for example we have 3 components : TestComponent, TestChildComponent, TestChildChildComponent

```
in app.module: { path: 'test' , component: TestListComponent },
               { path: 'test/:id', compomnent: TestChildListComponent },
               { path: 'test/:id/:id, component: TestChildChildListComponent }
```

they are linked by [routerLink], everything works fine, but how i can add N-child components?

Comment: What is "N-child components"?

Comment: i mean can i dynamically add routes

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756167/dynamic-routing-based-on-external-data/38096468#38096468